# Trouble getting SPFx up and running on Ubuntu

Tags: spfx, spfx-tooling, spfx-extensions

I'm having trouble getting SPFx up and running on Ubuntu. I'm using the following commands

sudo apt-get install nodejs -y

sudo apt-get update -y

sudo apt-get install build-essential -y

sudo npm install -g gulp -y

sudo npm install -g yo -y

sudo npm install -g @microsoft/generator-sharepoint

sudo mkdir helloworld-webpart

sudo cd helloworld-webpart

But when I start to make the template using the command:

sudo yo @microsoft/sharepoint

I get this message:

```
**Error: EACCES: permission dented, open ' /home/ubl/ . conftg/tnstght-nodejs/tnstght-yo. json.1337487756'**
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

try the last command without sudo:
$ yo @microsoft/sharepoint

but also try install nvm (https://github.com/creationix/nvm) for your nodejs environment, last time i tried in fedora 27, spfx only works with node 6.9, and node 8.2, not all versions of node works with spfx. The cross-platform is not "completely real" for SPFx, it works better in Win10 (of course) and macosx.